# VB.NET Adding list of property in Designer to choose from

Tags: vb.net, winforms, properties, designer

First excuse my my english, I'm french.

I have made a control (a class in fact) inherited from textbox.
The purpose of this class is simply to keep the textbox aligned above a column of a datagridview.

All is working correctly. But I have a question :
I made a datagridview property, and in design time, I can simply select it in a combobox listing the datagridview of my form.

But I have also a columnName property as a string. I would like that, once the datagridview is selected, the designer propose me the list of the datagridviewcolumn name in this property.

I have absolutly no idea how to achieve that. I'm a very beginner in code, and have made no studies on it.

I tried making the string property into a datagridviewcolumn property, but not only did the designer do not propose me the ones available, but also it crashes and I have to remove all about this textbox in the file.Designer.vb.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT : Here is the code :

```
Public Class TextBoxFilter
    Inherits TextBox

    Private WithEvents _DGV As DataGridView = Nothing
    Public Property DGV As DataGridView
        Get
            Return _DGV
        End Get
        Set(value As DataGridView)
            _DGV = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ColumnName As String = String.Empty
    Public Property ColumnName As String
        Get
            Return _ColumnName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ColumnName = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

The rest of the code is irrelevant. Just know that it features event (when datagridviewcolumns are move, not displayed, not visible) to adjust the textbox.

To answer Plutonix, I would like to be able to give the designer a list of column, even if there is several datagridview in the form, and even if it can't find them automatically. I suppose I could do that in the set of the datagridview ? But I don't know how.

Comment: Since there can be more than one DGV per form, and DataGridViewColumns are Components but a DGVColumn can only be related to one DGV, I might try to skip specifying the DGV and just select the column.  Ultimately though it might be easier to relocate the TB when the DGV Column is moved.  Hard to be more helpful without the code.  See: [Ask] and also take the [Tour]

Comment: Code added and question precised :)

Comment: It requires a custom designer class or UITypeEditor so you can inspect the DGV at design-time for column names.  And you still have a very tricky problem when you remove the column from the DGV, thus invalidating the textbox.  The KISS approach is to just use an *int* property that stores the column number.

Comment: I won't use index because I have a class which can hide and select columns to display (visible or not). And I saw before that indexes in this case are not very reliable. Anyway, I will just define column name in form loading to avoid typo (dgv.columns(col.name)). Too bad, it's great to see the textboxes aligning themselves in the designer.